# signalR .net core 3.1 and ionic 5 + angular 8 duplicates messages when stop and start hub

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ionic-framework, signalr

I'm using SignalR in .net core 3.1 project as a server and ionic 5 + angular 8 as a client, I have strange behavior with bub connection, for each stop/start hub the message is further duplicated.
First time one message, second time 2 duplicated messages, third time 3 duplicated messages etc.

@aspnet/singalr version is 1.1.4

The server code is:

```
services.AddSignalR();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>("/myHub");
            });
```

HubManager

```
public class MyHubManager<T> : IMyHubManager<T> where T : class
{
    private IHubContext<MyHub> context;

    public MyHubManager(IHubContext<MyHub> context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task SendGroupMessageAsync(string groupId, T message)
    {
        await context.Clients.Group(groupId).SendAsync(groupId , message);
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { NewMessage } from '../new.message';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {

    private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection
    public message$: Subject<NewMessage> = new Subject<NewMessage>();

    constructor() {
    }

    public init(id: string, hub: string, token: string) {
        if (!this.hubConnection) {
            console.log('init signalR');
            this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                .withUrl(`http://ipaddress/${hub}?groupId=group${id}`, {
                    accessTokenFactory: () => token
                })
                .build();
            this.hubConnection.start().then(() => {
                console.log('hub connection started');
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });

            this.hubConnection.on(`group${id}`, (message: NewMessage) => {
                console.log('signalR pass message');
                this.message$.next(message);
            });
        }
    }

    public closeConnection() {
        if (this.hubConnection) {
            console.log('close connection');
            this.hubConnection.stop();
            this.hubConnection = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The subscription is in another page using singalR service

```
export class MyPage {

  constructor(private signalRService: SignalRService) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
          this.initSignalRConnection();
  }

  initSignalRConnection(){
    this.signalRService.init('1234', 'myHub', 'token');
    this.signalRService.message$.subscribe((message: NewMessage) => {
      console.log('got message');
      this.handleMessage(message);
    });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave(){
    this.signalRService.closeConnection();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post what changes you did to make this working? I am stuck in this same issue and my html view is not getting updated upon the SignalR update reload. I am using async operator in my HTML template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages aren't duplicated, you just handle them multiple times. This happens because you always call `this.signalRService.message$.subscribe` on connect and never perform unsubsribe on disconnect.

Comment: Yessss that was the issue, I finally got it :) thank you!